# Override User model

Tags: strongloop

I am trying to override the login function for user. My user.js file under common/models does not seem to work.

```
User.beforeRemote('login', function(context, unused, next) {
  console.log(context);
  next();  
});
```

I have also tried this with not success:

```
User.on('attached', function() {
   var override = User.login;
   User.login = function(filter, callback) {
       console.log("Finally overridden!");
       return override.apply(this, callback);
   }
});
```

This code doesn't seem to be evaluated/run at all in user.js so maybe that's the problem? Do I need to tell strongloop somewhere that I have this file? I thought it was automatic.